# <video> tag no longer working in new update of iOS 10 iPad Safari

Tags: ios, angularjs, html, video, safari

I have an Angular app displaying a video like this:

```
<video ng-if="videoToPresent.shouldShow" width='640' height='360' controls autoplay>
    <source ng-src="{{videoToPresent.url}}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

This worked perfectly on mobile Safari until the new iOS 10 update. Now, it renders the video poster and the play button in the center, but it does nothing upon clicking the play button.

[I read an article](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) in WebKit's blog describing how use of the `playsinline` attribute is supported, so I tried adding that as well but without any success.

Anyone know what's going on with the new update? Thanks!

Comment: hmm, I seem to remember `ng-src` not working correctly on the `<source>` element. Try adding it to the `<video>` element and see what happens

Comment: Found a similar issue with iOS 10, which seems to be related to the crossorigin flag. For me, the first HEAD call is sent with the authorization cookie - but the next GET call is sent without - causing the server to respond with an unauthorized response.

Comment: @Mystogan I have a strange issue with video playback on iOS 10 too, on iOS 9 it works fine. In my case the video source points to an URL which redirects.

Comment: @Mystogan I wonder if it's same kind of issue. How did you fix yours?

Comment: @AndreiN. I have yet to solve this. I posted the details in my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636103/video-requiring-asp-net-authentication-not-working-on-ios-10