# Cordova app videos not playing on iOS10 - 401 error

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using Cordova and have added the iOS platform.

One of our test phones is running iOS 10 and for some reasons it won't play videos.

Prior to iOS 10 everything worked perfectly.

We currently are getting 401 errors on the server.

Thought it might possibly be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636103/video-requiring-asp-net-authentication-not-working-on-ios-10) issue.

I also note [these](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) WebKit changes.

Anyone come across anything similar?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround the suggestion made by **Kalle** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636103/video-requiring-asp-net-authentication-not-working-on-ios-10) worked for me. i.e.

> "Set an expire date to the cookie and the video player in iOS 10 can read back the cookie. Session cookies without an expire date can not be read back by the video player in iOS 10."

You can also test that this is your problem by trying [this](https://www.bizify.me/test-if-your-ios-device-is-broken/).

**NB** If you are using Tomcat, as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933143/jsessionid-cookie-with-expiration-date-in-tomcat), you can set expire date like this (in your web.xml):

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <max-age>7200</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Obviously change the values to fit your requirements.